# How does clDefault color work?

Tags: delphi, colors

I noticed some unusual behaviors using `clDefault` color.

```
clDefault = TColor($20000000); //536870912
```

As an example (http://wiki.freepascal.org/Colors):

> - Using it for Brush will use the normal background brush of the target
>     DC (device context).
> - On a Form's canvas a FillRect will paint a
>     rectangular area filled with the normal background of a standard
>     window. This is whatever the widgetset and theme defines. This might
>     be the color gray or a gradient or a picture.
> - Using clDefault on the
>     Canvas of a TListBox will paint with the normal background, which is
>     normally white on Windows. So in a TListBox clDefault is the same as
>     clWindow.
> - Using it as Pen color will use the default line color for
>     the device context.
> - Using it as Font color will use the normal text
>     color of the device context.

Could someone tell me how `clDefault` works?

I mean, is it interpreted by the OS or by the VCL code and how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You provide a link to FPC documentation, but then talk about the VCL and tag the question Delphi. I'm going to assume that you are asking about Delphi VCL and just ignore your linked documentation which does not apply.

In the VCL, for pens, fonts, and brushes, the default color is black. That's because `$20000000` has 0 for R, G and B channels. The alpha channel is `$20`, but is ignored, certainly for methods like `LineTo`, `FillRect`, etc. This is quite different from the FPC documentation you linked to.

If you use `clDefault` for the `Color` of a `TListBox`, then it will again be black. Again, different from the FPC documentation you linked to.

Certainly the value `$20000000` has no special meaning to GDI. For pens, fonts, brushes etc. the value is passed down to GDI which interprets it as black.

If you study the VCL source code you will find a variety of places where `clDefault` is used. In the main `clDefault` is used as a [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value). The VCL code checks whether or not a specified color property is equal to `clDefault`, and then takes special action if it is.

So far as I can tell, that's all there is to it. Some parts of the VCL treat `clDefault` as a sentinel, otherwise it is black.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've linked FPC documentation because I didn't find any Delphi documentation about clDefault and I wrongly thought that it was managed in the same way. I've removed quote and link. Anyhow, you've fully clarified all doubts, thanks for your answer!

Comment: @ExDev, [From Colors in the VCL-System Colors:](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Colors_in_the_VCL#System_Colors) *clDefault The default color for the control to which the color is assigned*.

Comment: OK, but then most of my answer makes next to no sense. So I reverted your question so that I didn't have to re-write my answer to match! Hope that's OK.

Comment: @LURD Yeah, that's all I found, and it's really useless isn't it!

Comment: Note that `TColor` values are not always GDI colours. If the top byte is set, that has a special meaning, usually for a system colour, e.g. `clBtnFace`. That is why you have functions like `Vcl.Graphics.ColorToRGB()` etc. `clDefault` is one of those special colours.